# Unable to install emacs24 on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa, emacs

I've added the cassou ppa, but when I try to install emacs24 or emacs-snapshot, apt-get can't seem to find the right packages:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cassou/emacs
...
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get install emacs24 emacs24-el emacs24-common-non-dfsg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package emacs24
E: Unable to locate package emacs24-el
E: Unable to locate package emacs24-common-non-dfsg
$ sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package emacs-snapshot is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'emacs-snapshot' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: now try `sudo apt-get -f install` this may fix it

Comment: Try making sure via `apt-cache search emacs`

Comment: The instructions in the cassou ppa don't make sense to me. Your command is the same as in the ppa, but I was also unable to locate the missing packages from your terminal error message in the cassou ppa package list. I suggest that you report a possible bug to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/emacs-snapshot/

Comment: The current version of Emacs in Ubuntu 12.04 is Emacs 23.3.1 not quite what you wanted, but it works OK.

Comment: @karel Emacs 24 is very different from 23. Lots of plugins depend on 24, for example.

Comment: Reported. https://bugs.launchpad.net/emacs-snapshot/+bug/1214053